# Labeled continue statement; for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

`continue connloop;` throws `Syntax Error: Unsyntactic continue`.

If I change `continue connloop;` to `continue;` , it will run (but ofcourse it will not execute on the outer loop but on the inner one)

Why is this happening, is this deprecated or illegal in nodejs/ecma6?

Please do not recommend me to use function calls instead of labels.

```
redisSubscriber.on("message", function(channel, event){

event = JSON.parse(event);
const eventPayload = JSON.stringify(event.payload);

 connloop:
  for(let conn in connections){
  conn = connections[conn];
  redisClient.SMEMBERS('connection/'+conn.id+'/subscriptions', (err, subscriptions)=>{

      let intersectedTags = [];
      if(event.address.tags.length > 0 && subscriptions.length > 0){         
        for(let tag in subscriptions){
          tag = subscriptions[tag];

          for(let _tag in event.address.tags){
            _tag = event.address.tags[_tag];
            if(tag == _tag)
              intersectedTags.push(tag);

          }
        }
      }

      let exclusive = false;
      for(let userId in event.address.include){
        userId = event.address.include[userId];
        if(userId == conn.userId){
          exclusive = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if(intersectedTags.length > 0 || exclusive){
        if(event.address.exclude){
          for(let exclude in event.address.exclude){
            exclude = event.address.exclude[exclude];
            if(exclude == conn.userId){
              continue connloop;
            }
          }
        }
        const browserEvent = {tags: intersectedTags, notification: eventPayload, exclusive};
        conn.write(JSON.stringify(browserEvent));
      }
  })
} });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using continue label out of closure function is unsyntactic, because of difference scope with continue statement and label connloop:

```
// continue statement in anonymous function
redisClient.SMEMBERS('connection/'+conn.id+'/subscriptions', (err, subscriptions)=>{
```

follow codes should be OK with same scope:

```
redisSubscriber.on("message", function(channel, event){

connloop:
    for(let conn in connections){
        // more codes ...
        for(let exclude in event.address.exclude){
            exclude = event.address.exclude[exclude];
            if(exclude == conn.userId){
               continue connloop;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`continue` is not valid across function boundaries. You put the `continue` inside a function, trying to jump to a position outside the function.

It also doesn't make sense to have a `continue` there since `redisClient.SMEMBERS` is most likely an asynchronous operation, so the loop already terminated by the time the callback is called.